# Embedding other programs in an Electron app

Tags: javascript, python, linux, functional-programming

I have recently begun working with JavaScript and have learned of the Electron framework. I am very interested in this framework (and the whole web technologies for desktop use concept). My programming capabilities could be best described as hobbyist. I have written a few small games and apps for my own use, and have a number of shell scripts to help me automate some of my workflow in Linux. My question is, is it possible to use an Electron app that is powered by a language other than JavaScript? For example, I have a bunch of Python scripts (and recently, some Haskell and F# ones too) to help me with my statistics, calculus, and accounting courses in school. I don't mind running a bunch of different scripts to do what I want but lately I've gotten the idea of potentially making some of them available for general distribution. But my scripts are, as I mentioned, written in several different languages, most of them functional languages and none of them in JavaScript. Is it possible to wrap these scripts into something like an Electron app? If not, does JavaScript have any features similar to a functional language? How would one go about creating a JavaScript library or framework to fullfil this need?

I am aware of platforms like SageMath and GNU Octave, but the whole point is to create something of my own.

I would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is there's no direct/easy way to do what you want.

But you have some options.

There's a [Electron compiler](https://github.com/electron/electron-compile), but it works only with Javascript based languages like TypeScript and CoffeeScript.

You can, of course, develop a local web application and communicate with your Electron UI using HTTP requests, [here](https://www.fyears.org/2015/06/electron-as-gui-of-python-apps.html) is an example using Python.

You can also use sockets for interprocess communication: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-ipc-socket

And you also has the option to just start a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) directly from your Electron Application.

Hope it helps and don't make you more confuse :)